# Why items are inversed inside container?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a popup window in which items are inversed for some reason . And i dont know why. I am creating a react-app using tailwindcss as css framework.
This is my styles :

```
  .dark {

    @apply w-full h-full fixed top-0 z-10 left-0 flex items-center justify-center;

    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);

    .content {

      @apply w-[90%] h-fit bg-softBlue rounded-3xl flex;

      .mangaImage {

        @apply m-0 w-[300px] h-[400px]
      }

      .description {

        @apply text-white text-xl max-w-[50%]
      }
    }
  }
```

And this is my react component :

```
const MangaPopUp = ({close , id}) => {
    const {data , loading,error} = useQuery(GET_MANGA_BY_ID , {
        variables: {
            "id": id
        }
    })

    return (
            <div className={styles.dark} onClick={close}>
                <div className={styles.content} onClick={e => {
                    e.stopPropagation()
                }}>
                    {(data && !error) && (
                        <>
                            <LazyImage onLoad={() => {}}
                                           onClick={() => {}} alt={"Обкладинка манґи"}
                                           imageUrl={MANGA_IMAGE_WAY + data.getManga.image.filename}
                                           className={styles.mangaImage}/>
                            <div className={styles.description}>
                                {data.getManga.description}
                            </div>
                        </>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
    );
};

export default MangaPopUp;
```

**Here is screenshot how its looking**
[image]

Yeah , i can fix it by writing justify-end property , but I want to know a reason why children are  behaving like this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I dont know where but this element has direction property with valie rtl , so i just changed it to :

```
direction: ltr;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).